# How to render data from model to view?

Tags: python, django

I have this model called Coach and I want it to be accessible in the lesson_detail.html, because when I use the template {{ coach.first_name }}, nothing is showing up. I'm trying to pull the data from the model using get_object_or_404 but I'm not sure what I need to put in the argument for that. I tried a few things like id=pk or in the code below, first_name=first_name, but I got an error that the variable is not defined.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.views import generic, View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Lesson, Coach, Feedback
from .forms import FeedbackForm

class LessonDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(status=1)
        lesson = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        coach = get_object_or_404(Coach, first_name=first_name)
        feedbacks = lesson.feedbacks.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
        liked = False
        if lesson.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "lesson_detail.html",
            {
                "lesson": lesson,
                "feedbacks": feedbacks,
                "coach": coach,
                "submitted_feedback": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "feedback_form": FeedbackForm(),
            },
        )
```

models.py

```
class Coach(models.Model):
    RECREATIONAL = 'recreational'
    FREESTYLE = 'freestyle'
    DANCE = 'dance'
    PAIRS = 'pairs'

    SPECIALIZATION_CHOICES = [
        (RECREATIONAL, 'Recreational'),
        (FREESTYLE, 'Freestyle'),
        (DANCE, 'Dance'),
        (PAIRS, 'Pairs'),
    ]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a brief bio")
    image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SPECIALIZATION_CHOICES, default=RECREATIONAL)
    years_of_experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='1', help_text="Enter a positive integer.")
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Coach {self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Comment: print(coach.__dict__) result ?

Comment: Can you please show the *full* traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hey! where do i find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `coach = get_object_or_404(Coach, first_name=first_name)` is your issue. `first_name=first_name` won't work because `first_name` is undefined.

While the variable *is* defined in the `Coach` class, you don't ever define it in `LessonDetail`. To fix the issue, define `first_name` in `LessonDetail` before using it.

It is possible to solve the main problem in two (or more) different ways. I'll go through what they are.

*Defining the variable*

As I said, defining `first_name` should do the trick. This is possible by accessing `Coach.objects.first()`. If we assign that to `coach`, we can simply define `first_name`: `first_name = coach.first_name`.

This is acts as a query. It obtains the *first* "coach" in the database in the deal is done, so to speak.

It also provides zero help when it comes to deleted records. You run the risk of referencing nonexistent entries.

*Relationship*

You can create a relationship with your `Coach` model. For example:

```
coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This creates link with the model via [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Then, all you need is:

```
lesson = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
coach = lesson.coach
```

in place of

```
lesson = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
coach = get_object_or_404(Coach, first_name=first_name)
```

This creates a relationship. With the parameter `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, you are easily able to delete a coach and everything associated with the coach is removed with it.

In general, the relationship route is a preferable route.

Comment: so I'd have to define first_name in LessonDetail like
first_name = Coach.objects.first_name
????

Comment: @yamesjames I believe you would have to get the actual object first for Django. So `coach = Coach.objects.first()` and then `first_name = Coach.first_name`. I am checking on thing in the documentation to see if I can get you a solid answer to this that's a bit more elegant.

Comment: if i want to access all the items in the Coach model, then would `coach = Coach.objects.first()` be enough?

Comment: @yamesjames. It should be. However, I'm updating my answer to include a more Django-y solution, but the above will work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still trying to figure it out, not sure if I understand everything but trying my best!

Comment: @yamesjames I substantially updated my answer with perhaps a better solution to your issues.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I did have the `coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` on my Lesson model, so the `coach = lesson.coach` made it work!